# ubuntu 12.10 64-bit consuming 100% cpu power and high battery

Tags: performance, battery, cpu

I am new linux user, installed ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit) from wubi (getting boot option (windows7/ubuntu).

But after opening ubuntu, laptop gets heat up, fan running very fast and performance is very poor, while installing graphics driver it hangs and i have to shut system by long pressing power button.

Battery backup ends very soon ( almost 1/5 as compared to win 7)

I installed powertop, it is showing 100% cpu usage.

I searched for the problem, but there are many solutions given online, i have tried some but no success.

system specs:
hp pavilion dv4, Intel core i5 (2nd gen), 6 gb ram

Comment: Paste the output of top command.

Comment: @Abhijeet : After trying many things, i uninstalled ubuntu to save my machine from any unknown damage. 

The top command was showing max 6% cpu usage per process.
and power top command was showing 100% cpu usage.

as i am a new linux user, i didnt understand rest of terms completely..

If this is important, then i can reinstall it, it will take 15 minutes..